# openpyxl module (Python): how can I get the coordinates of a cell when I know the string value of that cell?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have been working on a project that automates some Excel calculations. Somewhere in my code (I cannot share it because of confidentiality) I need to retrieve the coordinates of cells from which I know the values.

I know how to find the values, when I have the coordinates, but how does the other way round work?

Answer (score 0):

For example...

> A1 = 5, B1 = 6

Your code should be:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\demo.xlsx"

# workbook object is created
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
 
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 2) = sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 1) + sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = 2)

x = sheet_obj.cell(row = 2, column = 2)

print(x.value) #that can be access 
wb_obj.save('logo.xlsx')
```

Now you can access the value that's in `x`

Comment: I am not sure if this answers my question. I need to get the coordinates of a cell of which I know the (string) value.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my solution (works for string search values)

Contents of my file ('Book1.xlsx'):
[Image of my data in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ3Ht.png)

```
###############################################################
# Import openpyxl
# Note: openpyxl package provides both read and write capabilities to excel
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter


# Class definitions should use CamelCase convention based on pep-8 guidelines
class CustomOpenpyxl:

    # Initialize the class with filename as only argument
    def __init__(self, _my_file_name):
        assert _my_file_name.split('.')[-1] == 'xlsx', 'Input file is not xlsx'
        self.my_filename = _my_file_name
        self.my_base_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(self.my_filename, read_only=False)
        # following line will set the last worksheet in the workbook as active
        self.my_base_active_ws = self.my_base_wb.active

    # Method to get values for specific row in a given worksheet
    # Argument to this method is: - Row number of values to be fetched
    def get_specific_row_val_as_list_in_active_ws(self, _val_row_num):
        for _col in self.my_base_active_ws.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=1):
            # Iterate once for the specific row number in active worksheet
            for _row in self.my_base_active_ws.iter_rows(min_row=_val_row_num, max_row=_val_row_num):
                # Return a list of values
                return [_cell.value for _cell in _row]

    # Method to get cell coordinate by a search value
    # Argument to this method is:- search string
    # Assumption cell value is unique
    def get_cell_coordinate_by_value(self, _search_val):
        # List comprehension to get the row index based on the search value
        _row_processor = [_row_idx for _row_idx, _main_rec in enumerate(self.my_base_active_ws.values, start=1) if
                          _search_val in _main_rec]
        # return type is a list, hence following line to assign it to variable and manage the data type later
        _row_idx = _row_processor[-1]
        # Get the value of the entire row and fetch the column index
        _col_processor = [_col_idx for _col_idx, _val in
                          enumerate(self.get_specific_row_val_as_list_in_active_ws(int(_row_idx)), start=1) if
                          _val == _search_val]
        # retrun type is a list, hence following line to assign it to variable and manage the data type later
        _col_idx = _col_processor[-1]
        # get the column letter
        _col_letter = get_column_letter(int(_col_idx))
        # string concatenation to join column letter and row index
        _cell_address = _col_letter + str(_row_idx)
        return _cell_address


_my_file_name = 'Book1.xlsx'

# Instantiate an object using the newly created class in this code block
# So that this object gets access to all methods in the class
_my_src_obj = CustomOpenpyxl(_my_file_name)
print(_my_src_obj.get_cell_coordinate_by_value('BAGS'))
print(_my_src_obj.get_cell_coordinate_by_value(1000))

####################################################################PRINT Result################################################################################

B2
C4

Process finished with exit code 0
```